# Bootstrap 4 Display Display Property will not work with jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am attempting to show some html (in this case a table) that is imported using jQuery.load() along with bootstrap display property. Here is the code:

```
                  <div class="table d-none d-lg-block" style="width: 100%">
                    <div id="includedContent"></div>    
                  </div>

                  <div class="table-responsive d-lg-none d-xl-none" style="width: 100%">
                    <p>John Doe</p>
                    <div id="includedContent"></div>
                  </div>
```

As you can see, the bottom included content should only show below large- and this does indeed work, the "John Doe" only appears below large- and the above table gets hidden. The issue is however that the included content will not appear. Here is my code for the included content:

```
$("#includedContent").load("bigdatatable.html", function(){
  /// new html exists now
  $('#myTable').DataTable(/*options*/)
});
```

Any ideas? Is it that since the table has already been called, it remains hidden and isn't recalled? Thanks.

**EDIT: If I switch around the order, it does the opposite- the table shows below large, but doesn't show above it.**

```
                  <div class="table-responsive d-lg-none d-xl-none" style="width: 100%">
                    <p>John Doe</p>
                    <div id="includedContent"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="table d-none d-lg-block" style="width: 100%">
                    <div id="includedContent"></div>    
                  </div>
```

Comment: You have 2 divs using the same id ```includedContent```

Comment: That is true- but even when I create a duplicate, it still doesn't work. How do I fix this?